# How can I make my regular expression match variables inbetween brackets on single and multiple lines?

Tags: regex, typescript, grep

I am trying to match all environment variables that get de-structured from `process.env` in my Typescript project. This includes matching de-structuring on single or multiple lines.

Take the following TS code examples that contains de-structuring from process.env, 1 is on a single line, the other is across multiple lines:

**File1.ts:**

```
const { OKTA_AUDIENCE_DOMAIN, OKTA_DOMAIN = '', OKTA_WEB_CLIENT_ID, OKTA_ISSUER: issuer = '', AUTH_TWO: ISSUE_TWO = '', } = process.env;
```

**File2.ts:**

```
const {
  OKTA_AUDIENCE_DOMAIN,
  OKTA_DOMAIN = '',
  OKTA_WEB_CLIENT_ID,
  OKTA_ISSUER: issuer = '',
  AUTH_TWO: ISSUE_TWO = '',
} = process.env;
```

I have only been able to write a script that matches the de-strucutred variables on the single line. However, I want the script to match single and multi lines.

This is the script I currently have:

```
grep -Ezo '\{[^}]*\} = process.env' File1.ts
```

If ran on `File1`, I would get the following output, which is what I expect:

```
{ AUTH0_AUDIENCE_DOMAIN, AUTH0_DOMAIN = '', AUTH0_WEB_CLIENT_ID, AUTH0_ISSUER: issuer = '', AUTH_TWO: ISSUE_TWO = '', } = process.env
```

You can see here that it has correctly matched the environment variables being de-structured from process.env

Now if I were to run this same script on `File2.ts`, it would return nothing:

```
grep -Ezo '\{[^}]*\} = process.env' File2.ts
```

The output is empty.

How can I modify this script such that it matches the environment variables being de-structured on both **single and multiple lines**?

Comment: Have you tried with this line of code for match single or multiple lines.
`grep -EzoP '\{(.|\n)*\} = process.env' File2.ts`

Comment: Parsing [AST](https://ts-ast-viewer.com/#code/N4KABGDGD2B2DOAXMwwHkDSAVAggfRwFUARASQFEA5AYXL2LQFkdTKAadbfB51sAXjAByIR0y48AdXIAhPNQAyFSljyliYrmoDK2wuQBKALjABLePACuAUwBOA4aLBEsACTxZJaE6V36PXg4iHAC+DgAOttCQ1hYAdNawAG4A3CAhICCgEDAIyNkQnBJEZFS09Ews7OCF4tyVfILBNRB1UrLySlSq6mwtRfi+eoYm5lZ2QaL9Lu6e3mBD-nOTfRBhgpHRsfAJyWkZQA) is a better way to approach this.

Comment: @NIKUNJKOTHIYA this gives me the following error "grep: conflicting matchers specified"

Comment: Try `grep -Eo '\{(.|\n)*\} = process.env' File2.ts` or `grep -Po '\{(.|\n)*\} = process.env' File2.ts`

Comment: Both of these return nothing. When I run the -Po option, it will return 2 empty lines. @NIKUNJKOTHIYA

Comment: I need to check again. Thanks for confirming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
cat File1.ts | tr '\n' ' ' | sed 's/  */ /g' | grep -Ezo '\{[^}]*\} = process.env'
cat File2.ts | tr '\n' ' ' | sed 's/  */ /g' | grep -Ezo '\{[^}]*\} = process.env'
```

Notes:

- `tr` changes newlines to spaces (change to `tr '\n\r' '  '` if you are on Windows)
- `sed` gets rid of multiple spaces
- `grep` has your original parameters

Answer (score 0):

If you are okay with installing [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep)

```bash
rg -oU '\{[^}]*\} = process\.env'
```

The `-U` option enables multiline matching.

That said, `grep -oz '{[^}]*} = process\.env'` works for me for your given input samples. Also, note that with `grep -z` the output will be terminated with ASCII NUL characters. So, you'll need to further process the output, for example pipe to `tr '\0' '\n'`

Comment: I didn't get a chance to do this - I would prefer using grep as it comes pre-installed on all machines! Thx for your input